# Access USSD number in iOS via CoreTelephony framework and CTCallDialWithID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-telephony

I need to call a USSD number that contains * and # in iphone (iOS)
it tried a "tel:*100#" but this way dose not work with USSD characters

I found some solution via ***CoreTelephony framework by using CTCallDialWithID method***,
**But** is it legal or illegal  ??
 is it private or public API ??
can it casing apple rejection for my app??

If CoreTelephony is illegal to use or private,
How can i call USSD number?
is there any solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible (legally), opening URLs including USSD characters (encoded, not encoded etc) will be accepted (`[[UIApplication  sharedApplication]openUrl:]` return true), but the phone will never try to dial the number. I guess they're doing some validation on the tel-URLs.

I guess there's just too many security issues with allowing this. The story is the same on Android too.

Comment: I don't think there is any problems sending USSD calls on Android. So why do you say "the story is the same on Android" ?